# Display file link after selecting the file from file upload in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

How to get the local file path after selecting the file from the file upload... I need the file path to be appended to the href attribute of the anchor tag after selecting the file so that I can click on the link to open the file or view it...  How to do this using jQuery...

```
<input type="file" id="upload" name="fileupload" />
<a href="" target="_blank">View File</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done due to privacy issues with JS.

You may want to look at using some type of content viewer on your page to generate a preview of the uploaded content, although it greatly depends on the content type (I have only ever had to do this with images, which are pretty easy to preview in this way).